# Error linking C and Fortran in installation of library

Tags: c, macos, fortran, gfortran

I'm installing LoopTools version 2.15 (http://www.feynarts.de/looptools/LT25Guide.pdf), a library which evaluates special functions needed in physics. I had already installed it on a computer with Linux, and am now trying to install it on a Mac. I had to install a fortran compiler, which I did easily through macports. However, the following error appears when I try to install the package:

```
looking for gcc... /usr/bin/clang
looking for g++... /usr/bin/clang++
looking for fortran... /opt/local/bin/gfortran
extracting the Fortran libraries... ok
does gfortran append underscores... error linking Fortran and C
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to solve the problem?

EDIT: under suggestion, I post the last 30 lines of the logfile

````
+ eval setflags CXXFLAGS '-O3 -g -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -Wall  '
++ setflags CXXFLAGS -O3 -g -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -Wall
++ rhs=
++ printf -v rhs ' %q' -O3 -g -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -Wall
++ eval 'CONF_CXXFLAGS="${rhs//\\,/,}"'
+++ CONF_CXXFLAGS=' -O3 -g -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -Wall'
+ echo -n 'does gfortran append underscores... '
+ tee test32232-c.c
int uscore_ = 95;
int uscore = 59;
+ for CONF_BITS in '${CONF_BITS:--m64 -m32}'
+ eval clang -O3 -g -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -fPIC -Wall -m64 -c test32232-c.c
++ clang -O3 -g -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -fPIC -Wall -m64 -c test32232-c.c
+ eval gfortran -O3 -ffixed-line-length-none -fno-range-check -Wl,-no_compact_unwind -o test32232 test32232.f test32232-c.o
++ gfortran -O3 -ffixed-line-length-none -fno-range-check -Wl,-no_compact_unwind -o test32232 test32232.f test32232-c.o
ld: library not found for -lSystem
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
+ for CONF_BITS in '${CONF_BITS:--m64 -m32}'
+ eval clang -O3 -g -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -fPIC -Wall -m32 -c test32232-c.c
++ clang -O3 -g -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -fPIC -Wall -m32 -c test32232-c.c
+ eval gfortran -O3 -ffixed-line-length-none -fno-range-check -Wl,-no_compact_unwind -o test32232 test32232.f test32232-c.o
++ gfortran -O3 -ffixed-line-length-none -fno-range-check -Wl,-no_compact_unwind -o test32232 test32232.f test32232-c.o
ld: library not found for -lSystem
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
+ ./test32232
./configure: line 264: ./test32232: No such file or directory
+ case $? in
+ echo 'error linking Fortran and C'
+ exit 1
+ rm -fr test32232-c.c test32232-c.o test32232.f =.```
````

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell which version of LoopTools you tried to install. I checked version 2.15. The script `configure` can write the error output to a file if you set the environment variable `LOGFILE` to a file name. Otherwise the error output is discarded. Try e.g. `LOGFILE=log.txt` `export LOGFILE` `./configure` (as 3 separate commands) and show the last part of `log.txt` in your question, e.g. the output of `tail -30 log.txt`.

Comment: The version I tried to install is indeed LoopTools 2.15

Comment: After the command `gfortran ... -o test32232 test32232.f test32232-c.o` you can see the error message `ld: library not found for -lSystem`. Check if you have a library `libSystem.*` on your system and where it is located. If it's not in a standard location, maybe you have to add the library location to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and/or `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: `/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib` is part of the O/S.  I would suspect that fortran linker as being broken.

Comment: I searched for it and it is in the right folder

Comment: Does /opt/local/bin/ possibly have gcc and g++ installed by macports (not /usr/bin/clang)? Then, I guess explicitly specifying them as "CC=/opt/local/bin/gcc CXX=/opt/local/bin/g++ FC=/opt/local/bin/gfortran ./configure" might have different results. (FYI, the above Loop library just compiled w/o problem on my mac... I used GCC installed via homebrew.)

Comment: both clang (in /usr/bin ) and the macport-installed gcc, g++ and gfortran-mp-5/gfortran-mp-6 (in /opt/local/bin) are present. I tried setting the variables (is via terminal enough?) as you said but the result is not different