# compiling F90 code on mac osx catalina: library issues

Tags: macos, fortran, gfortran

Just upgraded to osx catalina. I have some F90 code to compile/run.
Running gfortran 8.2.0

Makefile is included below

I had to reinstall xcode and the command tools to be able to use "make", that seems fine, but when compiling with the attached makefile, at the last linking command, I get the following error. A google search does not return relevant issues, and I didn't see a related post on here. Has anyone come across this?

Thanks,

```
mpif90     -O3 -o bin/lare3d obj/shared_data.o obj/mpi_routines.o obj/openboundary.o obj/mpiboundary.o obj/boundary.o obj/normalise.o obj/conduct.o obj/diagnostics.o obj/setup.o obj/lagran.o obj/remap.o obj/xremap.o obj/yremap.o obj/zremap.o obj/initial_conditions.o obj/output_cartesian.o obj/iocontrol.o obj/output.o obj/iocommon.o obj/input.o obj/inputfunctions.o obj/input_cartesian.o obj/eos.o obj/neutral.o obj/control.o obj/welcome.o obj/lare3d.o


ld: library not found for -lSystem

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bin/lare3d] Error 1


MAKEFILE IS HERE:

# Set the compiler flags
#FFLAGS = -fast#-fast #-arch pn4 -tpp7 -tune pn4 -ax
#FFLAGS = -r8 -fast -fastsse -O3 -Mipa=fast -Minline -Munroll   #PGI optimised
#FFLAGS = -Mbounds -g               #PGI Debug
#FFLAGS = -O3 -fast                             #Intel
#FFLAGS = -fpe0 -nothreads -traceback -fltconsistency -CB -g  #Intel Debug
 
FFLAGS = -O3 #-fallow-argument-mismatch 

# Set some of the build parameters
TARGET = lare3d

#Uncomment the following line to use Qmono viscosity
#QMONO = -DQ_MONO

#Uncomment the following line to run in single precision
#QSINGLE = -DQ_SINGLE

#Uncomment the following line to use fourth order RK scheme for resistive update
#QFOURTHORDER = -DQ_FOURTHTORDER


# --------------------------------------------------
# Shouldn't need to touch below here
# --------------------------------------------------

SRCDIR = src
OBJDIR = obj
BINDIR = bin
MODULEFLAG = #-module
OPFLAGS = $(QMONO)  $(QSINGLE) $(QFIRSTORDER)
FC = mpif90 $(OPFLAGS)
PREPROFLAGS = $(NONMPIIO)

OBJFILES = shared_data.o mpi_routines.o openboundary.o mpiboundary.o boundary.o normalise.o conduct.o diagnostics.o setup.o lagran.o  \
 remap.o xremap.o yremap.o zremap.o initial_conditions.o\
 output_cartesian.o iocontrol.o output.o iocommon.o input.o inputfunctions.o\
 input_cartesian.o eos.o neutral.o control.o\
 welcome.o lare3d.o
FULLTARGET = $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)

#vpath %.f90 $(SRCDIR)
#vpath %.o $(OBJDIR)
VPATH = $(SRCDIR):$(OBJDIR):$(SRCDIR)/core:$(SRCDIR)/io/

# Rule to build the fortran files

%.o: %.f90
    @mkdir -p $(BINDIR) $(OBJDIR) 
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) -o $(OBJDIR)/$@ $<

%.o: %.F90
    @mkdir -p $(BINDIR) $(OBJDIR) 
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) -o $(OBJDIR)/$@ $(PREPROFLAGS) $<

$(FULLTARGET): $(OBJFILES)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS)-o $@ $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(OBJFILES))

.PHONEY: clean
clean:
    @rm -rf *~ $(BINDIR) $(OBJDIR) *.pbs.* *.sh.* $(SRCDIR)/*~ $(SRCDIR)/core/*~ $(SRCDIR)/io/*~ *.log

.PHONEY: tidy
tidy:
    @rm -rf $(OBJDIR) *.pbs.* *.sh.* $(SRCDIR)/*~ *.log

.PHONEY: touch
touch:
    @touch src/* ; touch src/core/* 

.PHONEY: datatidy
datatidy:
    @rm -rf Data/*

.PHONEY: visit
visit:
    @cd VisIT;xml2makefile -clobber cfd.xml;make

.PHONEY: visitclean
visitclean:
    @cd VisIT;make clean;rm -f .depend
# All the dependencies
shared_data.o:shared_data.F90
mpi_routines.o:mpi_routines.f90 shared_data.o 
normalise.o:normalise.f90 shared_data.o
setup.o:setup.F90 shared_data.o normalise.o iocommon.o iocontrol.o input.o input_cartesian.o
mpiboundary.o: mpiboundary.f90 shared_data.o
openboundary.o: openboundary.f90 shared_data.o
boundary.o:boundary.f90 shared_data.o mpiboundary.o 
xremap.o:xremap.f90 shared_data.o boundary.o
yremap.o:yremap.f90 shared_data.o boundary.o
zremap.o:zremap.f90 shared_data.o boundary.o
diagnostics.o:diagnostics.F90 shared_data.o boundary.o normalise.o output_cartesian.o output.o iocontrol.o eos.o
iocommon.o:iocommon.f90 shared_data.o
output.o:output.f90 shared_data.o iocommon.o
output_cartesian.o: output_cartesian.f90 shared_data.o iocommon.o output.o
iocontrol.o: iocontrol.f90 shared_data.o iocommon.o output.o input.o
input.o: input.f90 shared_data.o iocommon.o inputfunctions.o
inputfunctions.o: inputfunctions.f90 shared_data.o iocommon.o  
input_cartesian.o: input_cartesian.f90 iocommon.o inputfunctions.o
conduct.o:conduct.f90 shared_data.o boundary.o eos.o
lagran.o:lagran.F90 shared_data.o boundary.o diagnostics.o normalise.o eos.o neutral.o conduct.o
remap.o:remap.f90 shared_data.o xremap.o yremap.o zremap.o
initial_conditions.o:initial_conditions.f90 shared_data.o normalise.o eos.o neutral.o
eos.o:eos.F90 shared_data.o normalise.o
neutral.o: neutral.f90 shared_data.o boundary.o normalise.o eos.o
control.o: control.f90 shared_data.o normalise.o
welcome.o: welcome.f90 shared_data.o
lare3d.o:lare3d.f90 shared_data.o setup.o boundary.o diagnostics.o lagran.o remap.o mpi_routines.o welcome.o initial_conditions.o openboundary.o eos.o control.o
```

Comment: The same comments that I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64106767/how-can-i-solve-the-library-not-found-on-mac-when-compiling-a-fortran-code) apply . Please provide more information about your system. As much as you could. Otherwise it will result into the same situations as it happened for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63076385/gfortran-for-mac-error-ld-library-not-found-for-lsystem and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54120274/library-not-found-for-lsystem-in-gnu-fortran and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63032579/compiling-using-gfortran-in-mac ...

Comment: and  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57996656/error-linking-c-and-fortran-in-installation-of-library

Comment: Too many people have asked the same but never really provided any details that could result into a more useful answer than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56156520/gfortran-error-ld-library-not-found-for-lsystem-when-trying-to-compile

Comment: SOLVED: A fresh installation of xcode commandlinetools seemed to work.

Comment: That is good for you, but without those details we really do not know if it is a generic solution. You may want to write an answer at the linked question anyway.